# rangeOfString with special characters

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've created a string with a special character, and then I'm iterating over another NSString and trying to see if I find a match between my NSString of interest, and the new one. However, the rangeOfString seems to have a hangup with special characters.

Essentially this is the idea, and the problem is that NSLog never reads "Hurray!" since it doesn't find the square root symbol.

```
NSString *goal = @"√"

NSString *input =@"Messing with Sasquatch √"

int strLength = [input length];
int strpos = 0;
unichar ch = [input characterAtIndex:strpos];


while (strpos < strLength)
{
   ch = [input characterAtIndex:strpos];

   if ([goal rangeOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",ch]].location != NSNotFound)
      NSLog(@"Hurray!");

   ++strpos;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hangup? What's not working?

Comment: It doesn't ever say "Hurray" it never finds the sqrt character

Comment: You need to use `%C`, not `%c`. But why the loop? Why not just call `[input rangeOfString:goal]` once and look at the result?

Comment: @rmaddy Because I'm doing something specific on each character. This was just a generalization since I was being troubled by the special char problem. When I did this, the value of char was /U221a.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's unfortunate about this problem is that I orginally had written this in C, which is a far more efficient format for this goal. However, in this particular instance, I was able to solve it by simply staying true to NSString.

That is, instead of moving to char and then back, I just made a substr of length 1 as follows.

```
NSRange subRange = {strpos, 1};
NSString *substr = [input substringWithRange:subRange
```

Then, in the loop, just use substr as follows:

```
 if ([goal rangeOfString:substr].location != NSNotFound)
      NSLog(@"Hurray!");
```